# Running apple script trough launchctl not working BigSur

Tags: applescript, launchd, plist

I would like to run a short testing script in the background via `launchctl` that sends a notification every 10 seconds.

What I did so far:
I created a plist file named `test.plist` located in `/Library/LaunchAgents/` containing the following lines:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>test</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/usr/bin/osascript</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>osascript</string>
        <string>~/Desktop/test.scpt</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The command `plutil /Library/LaunchAgents/test.plist`  returns `OK`
The file `test.scpt` is an apple script located on the Desktop containing:

```
repeat
    display notification "HELLO WORLD" with title "TITLE"
    delay 10
end repeat
```

What I tried is the following:

- first I run `sudo chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchAgents/test.plist`
- after that `launchctl enable gui/501/test`
- then `launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Library/LaunchAgents/test.plist`
- followed by `launchctl kickstart -k gui/501/test`
- finally `launchctl start gui/501/test`

Until that moment I get no errors but nothing is happening (no notification)!
When checking `launchctl list` I obtain `-    1   test` for my process!

I tested this procedure placing my file in `Library/LaunchAgents`, `~/Library/LaunchAgents` and `Library/LaunchDeamons`. Same result.

How can I fix that?

Also during my testing I've added a lot of testing plists. How can I remove them?
`launchctl remove test` doesn't seems to work.

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka!

Found a solution: the problem was that my apple script was located on the Desktop. So I changed its location to `/Users/<my username>/Library/Scripts/` and modified also the path in the plist.

To remove the testing plists I did: `sudo nano /var/db/com.apple.xpc.launchd/disabled.*.plist`
removed the unwanted services and then rebooted.

Hope it helps.